# Unable to use multiple templates/controllers in same HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

In an Angular app, I need to include `A.html` along with its controller in `B.html` without duplicating either `A.html` or AController.

I wrote the following in A.html but it didn't work

```
<div ng-include src="src/html/v1/A.html"></div>
```

Following is the app's code structure

```
src
├── html
│   ├── v1
│   │   ├── A.html
│   │   ├── B.html
├── index.coffee
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── v1
│   │   │   ├── AController.js
|   │   │   ├── BController.js
└── sass
    ├── v1
```

Following is what index.coffee contains -

```
 $routeProvider
    .when("/",
      {
        templateUrl: "src/html/v1/A.html",
        title: "A"
        controller: "AController"
      })
    .when("/A",
      {
        templateUrl: "src/html/v1/A.html",
        title: "A"
        controller: "AController"
      })
    .when("/B",
      {
        templateUrl: "src/html/v1/B.html",
        title: "B"
        controller: "BController"
      })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" })
```

Please suggest what am I missing here.

PS: The answer to this question may be answer to many other similar questions but I couldn't find the answer at first instance. The upvotes to this question clearly tells that it holds relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` attribute for `ng-include` accepts an string. So change it to:

```
<div ng-include src="'src/html/v1/A.html'"></div>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

> angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string
>   constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g.
>   `src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"`.

Comment: on a sidenote, this mechanism doesn't include controller. only the HTML template is included.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<div ng-include src="'src/html/v1/A.html'"></div>`

Comment: As you posted the answer first, I have given an upvote to you but I have marked shashank-agrawal answer as correct as its better explained.